# Why my optional value is not unwrapped, Swift?

Tags: swift

I have pretty simple example and have no clue why it doesn't work as expected.

```
var list:Array<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5]

var item:Int?


for var index = 0; index < list.count; index++ {

   item! = list[index]

   item = item + 5 // <-- error value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped
}
```

Why Swift forces me to write: `item = item! + 5`

I unwrapped it here: `item! = list[index]` and if list returns `nil` - the Exception will be thrown.

As I understand on this step a.e.: `item! = list[index]` the `item` is not `nil`

I tried several options like:

- `item! = list[index] as Int!`
- `item! = list[index] as AnyOblect! as? Int`

But still get the same demand to write `item = item! + 5`

*I use playground*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me break it down for you:

- `var item:Int?` tells the compiler that whenever the word `item` is used, it refers to a variable of type **optional** `Int` (aka `Int?`).
- `var item:Int` on the other hand, tells the compiler that whenever the word `item` is used, it refers to a variable simply of type `Int`.
- In order to access the unwrapped value of your variable declared in `var item:Int?`, you will **always** have to use `item!`. The compiler is not going to guess whether the variable `item` has a value or not. That, after all, is the the whole purpose of optionals. To make it clear that these kind of variables **may or may not have a value**.
- Essentially, what I'm trying to say is that a variable once declared as an optional, will **always** be an optional regardless of whether it contains a value or not. To get the unwrapped value, you will always have to use the character `!`, unless you decide to store it's value in another variable (ex. `var unwrappedItem = item!`)

To get rid of your error, simply declare your `item` variable to be of type `Int`, and not `Int?`.

As to why Swift throws an error instead of just letting the runtime raise an exception, it's just an extra precaution to probably discourage people from using bad practice.

Comment: Even if I unwrapped it before like `item!`?